Sharepoint api not exposed when using graphApi token MSAL
So, I am trying to read data from SharePoint. Whenever I try to do this, I get the following error: AADSTS650053: The application 'Application' asked for scope 'AllSites.Read' that doesn't exist on the resource I receive same errors for write and read permissions. I have tried using the Graph API, but it did not work for my specific case.
This is the scope
        "User.Read",
        "Files.Read.All",
        "Files.Read",
        "Sites.Read.All", 
        "AllSites.Read",   
        "AllSites.Write",  
        "AllSites.Manage"  
    )

Sign in
I would say this is pretty stardar way of doing so
 private fun signIn() {
        val parameters = SignInParameters.builder()
            .withScopes(scopes)
            .withCallback(object : AuthenticationCallback {
                override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: IAuthenticationResult) {
                    mAccount = authenticationResult.account
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Sign-in successful access token : ${authenticationResult.accessToken}")
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Account: ${authenticationResult.account.username}")

                    // Fetch user data after successful sign-in

                }

                override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Sign-in failed: ${exception.message}")
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Sign-in cancelled")
                }
            })
            .withActivity(this)
            .build()

        mSingleAccountApp?.signIn(parameters)
    }

Initilization
  PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(
            this.applicationContext,
            R.raw.auth_config,
            object : IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener {
                override fun onCreated(application: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication) {
                    mSingleAccountApp = application
                    loadAccount()

                }

                override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "MSAL initialization failed: ${exception.message}")
                }
            })


Could you include what API permissions you granted in your application by editing your question?

@Sridevi  I have added te list of permission you have asked for

What exactly you want to read from SharePoint via Graph API?

I would like to acces microsoft list cells  and rows with data  @Sridevi

Are you getting error while generating access token?

I  am getting following error AADSTS650053: The application 'Application' asked for scope 'AllSites.Read' that doesn't exist on the resource while tryig to use the spopes while signing in otherwise when i try to fetch data from list list I just get fetch error 401

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Note that, you cannot combine both Microsoft Graph API and SharePoint API permissions in scope parameter.
Initially, I too got same error when I included SharePoint API permissions like AllSites.Read along with Microsoft Graph API permissions like User.Read in scope parameter while generating token:

To resolve the error, make sure to remove all SharePoint API permissions and add only Microsoft Graph related permissions as you are calling Microsoft Graph API to list items.
In my case, I added only Sites.Read.All Microsoft Graph permission of Delegated type in my app registration:

I generated the token by passing only Sites.Read.All in scope parameter. You can decode the token by pasting it in jwt.ms and check scp claim:

When I used this token to call below Graph API call, I got the response successfully with items in SharePoint list:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/lists/listId/items

Response:

In your case, remove all SharePoint API permissions from scope parameter and pass only Sites.Read.All  Microsoft Graph API permission.

The issue with this one was that MSAL requires us to use different authentication for the Sharepoint, so I had to use the Graph API access to get the files, not the REST Sharepoint, and removing these permission.

Can I post the answer with repro?

absolutely go ahead
